# jquery no funciona laravel 5.8

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

ojala me puedan ayudar con esto, siempre he tenido problemas que quiero implementar varios scripts con jquery pero a veces no me funcionan, y estoy seguro que estoy haciendo algo mal.

Estoy usando laravel 5.8 y deseo agregar en el registro de usuarios un [Password Strenght meter](https://github.com/ablanco/jquery.pwstrength.bootstrap/releases).

Agregue en mi layouts.app.blade.php el siguiente codigo:

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/i18next.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/pwstrength.js') }}"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function () {
          "use strict";
          i18next.init({
            lng: 'es',
            resources: {
              es: {
                translation: {
                  "wordLength": "Tu contrase&ntilde;a es demasiado corta",
                  "wordNotEmail": "No uses tu email como tu contrase&ntilde;a",
                  "wordSimilarToUsername": "Tu contrase&ntilde;a no puede contener tu nombre de usuario",
                  "wordTwoCharacterClasses": "Mezcla diferentes clases de caracteres",
                  "wordRepetitions": "Demasiadas repeticiones",
                  "wordSequences": "Tu contrase&ntilde;a contiene secuencias",
                  "errorList": "Errores:",
                  "veryWeak": "Muy D&eacute;bil",
                  "weak": "D&eacute;bil",
                  "normal": "Normal",
                  "medium": "Media",
                  "strong": "Fuerte",
                  "veryStrong": "Muy Fuerte",

                  "start": "Comience a escribir la contrase&ntilde;a",
                  "label": "Contrase&ntilde;a",
                  "pageTitle": "Bootstrap 4 Password Strength Meter - Ejemplo de Traducciones",
                  "goBack": "Atr&aacute;s"
                }
              }
            }
          }, function () {
            // Initialized and ready to go

            var options = {};
            options.ui = {
                container: "#pwd-container",
                showVerdictsInsideProgressBar: true,
                viewports: {
                    progress: ".pwstrength_viewport_progress"
                },
                showErrors: true
            };
            options.common = {
                debug: true,
                onLoad: function () {
                    $('#messages').html(i18next.t('start'));
                }
            };
            $(':password').pwstrength(options);

            $('.container').find('label').html(i18next.t('label')).end()
                           .find('h1').html(i18next.t('pageTitle')).end()
                           .find('a').html(i18next.t('goBack'));
          });
      });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Y esto es lo que tengo en el archivo views/auth/register

```
<div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="pwstrength_viewport_progress"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div id="messages" class="col-sm-12"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Y no me aparece nada en la pagina a la hora de guardar todos los archivos. En el ejemplo del script que descargue me funciona perfectamente cuando lo abro en html, pero estuve buscando alguna solucion y no encuentro alguna.

Gracias!!

Comment: En tu primer fragmento de código veo la llamada de 2 archivos `.js` pero nada de JQuery, ¿si lo estás invocando al inicio de los otros 2 archivos?

Comment: supuestamente laravel ya viene con jquery y el js de bootstrap (segun yo no tengo que agregarlos nuevamente o si?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Te falta llamar al JQuery que debes tenerlo instalado en la ruta /public , para este ejemplo mi ruta es /public/vendor/jquery:

```html
  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="{{ asset('vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Agregue lo que me comentas y me desactiva el dropdown del usuario registrado que ya viene por default laravel.